# Merge Multiple Excel Files and Keep the Tabs the Same

Tags: excel, vba

I have 7 Excel spreadsheets - each with 12 tabs - they're weekly spreadsheets so the number of spreadsheets increases every week (next week there will be 8 spreadsheets with 12 tabs each).  The tabs are the same on each spreadsheet respectively (the first tab is named Monday, the second tab Tuesday, etc.).  I want to be able to combine the sheets through VBA script and I have three requirements:

1. The source spreadsheets don't need to be open
2. I want to ADD the data to the identical tabs, so I want to add the Monday data, then for the second spreadsheet being imported add the Mondya data to the first available row on the bottom, etc.
3. In a perfect world I only need to add 2 of the 12 tabs from each worksheet (tabs 8 and 9)

I have the following script which combines the spreadsheets but it just adds all the tabs as new, so if I combine two spreadsheets it gives me 24 tabs instead of putting all the data on 12 tabs.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
  Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
  Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
  Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
  Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

  fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

  If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
      countFiles = 0
      countSheets = 0

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

      Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

      For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
          countFiles = countFiles + 1

          Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

          For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
              countSheets = countSheets + 1
              wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
          Next

          wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

      Next

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

      MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

  Else
      MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why not just loop through each spreadsheet in the various files, copy data, and paste to the end of the equivalent range in your master workbook?

Answer (score 0):

### Import Data From Closed Workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Import Data"

    Dim sNames(): sNames = Array( _
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", _
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
    Dim dNames(): dNames = Array( _
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", _
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")

    Dim sPaths: sPaths = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
        "Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", _
        Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If VarType(sPaths) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Operation canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, srg As Range, dfCell As Range, sPath, n As Long

    For Each sPath In sPaths
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
        For n = LBound(sNames) To UBound(sNames)
            With swb.Sheets(sNames(n)).UsedRange
                Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
            End With
            With dwb.Sheets(dNames(n)).UsedRange
                Set dfCell = .Cells(1).Offset(.Row.Count)
            End With
            srg.Copy dfCell
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next n
    Next sPath
    
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Vbasic2008.  I'm receiving a subscript error out of range message here: 
        
            With swb.Sheets(sNames(n)).UsedRange

Comment: The source workbook (`swb`) has no worksheet named `sNames(n)`. Check for trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Vbasic2008.  My workbooks have many sheets but I'm only attempting to bring over two - Visibility and Vehicle.  They both exist with no trailing spaces.                                             Dim sNames(): sNames = Array("Visibility", "Vehicle")
    Dim dNames(): dNames = Array("Visibility", "Vehicle")